# Ruby / Rails: using .find from Enumerator instead of ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Ruby's Enumerable has a select which can select certain items from an array:

```
parent=@sections.select { |p| p.id==i.parent_id }
```

There is also a .find method, to select just the first match. However, `parent=@sections.find { |p| p.id==i.parent_id }` calls the ActiveRecord method instead of the Enumerable one. How do I use the Enumerable .find method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
parent = @sections.all.find{|p| p.id == i.parent_id}
```

But why would you want to grab *all* of the records from the database and then perform a ruby find on them, when it is far far far more efficient to let the database do use it's relational magic and get the correct records *for* you based on the id's?

Getting all of the records and then doing a ruby find is not scalable at all - I learned this very quickly in my first database-driven applications when I would grab every single record and loop through them to collect the data I wanted.  It's no good at all.

You should just do `i.parent` assuming `i belongs_to :parents`

Comment: consider Document has_many Sections (a table of contents). I'm using nested_set and trying to generate an ordered list (<ol>) from the sections. Because of the implementation it will query the database every time I look for a parent, even though I have that parent in the @sections array from a previous query (@sections = @video.sections)

Comment: @waitinforatrain Well, if you want to not perform that query every time you try calling `i.parent` (Maybe I would understand better if I saw your specific code, had a bit of trouble 100% following that but I think I got it) then you can get the original collection using `@section = @video.sections(:include => :parent)` And that way when you call @section.first.parent it won't induce a new query.  But I see now where you were going with your ruby array find.

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable#detect` is an alias for `Enumerable#find`. I don't believe AR replaces it, so perhaps it will work for you.